# Did I sign a non-solicitation agreement? If so, how do I get out of it? [US, Massachusetts]

Tags: massachusetts, non-disclosure, non-compete

Exactly as I described: Wondering if the below contains a non-solicitation agreement or is it referring if any was signed in the past?

What are the terms here exactly?

*You acknowledge your continuing obligations to the Company contained in any proprietary rights or other confidentiality agreements that you signed in favor of the Company during your employment, including the Continuing Obligations Agreement you have previously signed related to confidentiality, non-solicitation of customers and employees, and intellectual property protection/inventions assignment. Notwithstanding the above, any prior noncompete restrictions are now waived by this Agreement.*

Answer (score 1):

It does not contain a non-solicitation agreement.  The relevant bits are "You acknowledge your continuing obligations to the Company contained in any ... agreements that you signed".

In other words, this doesn't create any new agreements - just reminds you about the existing ones.

I suspect *this* agreement actually has very little legal effect at all; if they want to sue, they will sue on the actual agreement where you agreed not to solicit customers.  What it does (they hope), is reduce the *need* to sue, by reminding you not to do it.

Comment: Sometimes formally reminding an employer of existing obligations is required as part of other contracts.  For example, the PCI contract requires employees to sign an "I will treat customer data properly" document every year.